# Page Scrolling jQuery function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2

The implementation thus far is a support-subform-box is created when the user clicks the button. I'm having trouble with getting the page to automatically scroll to that newly created box of fields (support-subform-box). I'm using this popular jQuery function so the page will scroll to the freshly created box when the user clicks a button:

```
function scroll()
        {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#js-section').offset().top
            }, 200);
        }
```

Button to add box/fields:

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="add_fields(); scroll()"> Add another operator </button>
</div>
```

This is how I'm creating the new box/fields

```
function add_fields() {
            room++;
            var objTo = document.getElementById('name_fields');
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
            var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
            divtest.innerHTML = '<h5 class="support-subform-label" style="text-align: left;">Equipment Operator(s) </h5> <div class="support-subform-box" id="js-section"> <label id="first_name-group" for="first_name" class="small-12 medium-6" style="text-align: left; float: left;"> First Name {{ form.first_name }} </label><label id="last_name-group" for="last_name" class="small-12 medium-6" style="text-align: left; float: right;"> Last Name {{ form.last_name }} </label><label for="email" style="text-align: left;"> Email {{ form.email }} </label><label id="phone-number-group" for="phone-number" class="small-12 medium-7" style="text-align: left; float: left;"> Phone Number {{ form.phone.number }} </label><label id="phone-extension-group" for="phone-extension" class="small-12 medium-5" style="text-align: left; float: left;"> ext {{ form.phone.extension }} </label><label class="small-12" style="text-align: left;"> Title {{ form.position }} </label> <br> <div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="remove_fields('+ room +');"> Remove </button> </div> </div>';

            objTo.appendChild(divtest)
        }
```

FYI: I'm using Jinja2/Flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a good idea to use an index to every new line added with the function

```
function add_fields() {
        room++; /* Using this index to indefy the #js-section id on scroll function*/
        var objTo = document.getElementById('name_fields');
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
        var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
        divtest.innerHTML = '<h5 class="support-subform-label" style="text-align: left;">Equipment Operator(s) </h5> <div class="support-subform-box" id="js-section'+ room +'"> <label id="first_name-group" for="first_name" class="small-12 medium-6" style="text-align: left; float: left;"> First Name {{ form.first_name }} </label><label id="last_name-group" for="last_name" class="small-12 medium-6" style="text-align: left; float: right;"> Last Name {{ form.last_name }} </label><label for="email" style="text-align: left;"> Email {{ form.email }} </label><label id="phone-number-group" for="phone-number" class="small-12 medium-7" style="text-align: left; float: left;"> Phone Number {{ form.phone.number }} </label><label id="phone-extension-group" for="phone-extension" class="small-12 medium-5" style="text-align: left; float: left;"> ext {{ form.phone.extension }} </label><label class="small-12" style="text-align: left;"> Title {{ form.position }} </label> <br> <div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="remove_fields('+ room +');"> Remove </button> </div> </div>';

        objTo.appendChild(divtest)
        scroll(room);
    }
```

Also, you can call the scroll function at the end of add_fields() function and give the index to make the selector get the specific id

```
 function scroll(indexid)
    {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#js-section'+indexid).offset().top
        }, 200);
    }
```

Finally, you only call add_fields from the HTML

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="add_fields();"> Add another operator </button>
```